# Remove parent categories from subcategory URLs

Tags: url-rewrite, htaccess, .htaccess

I realise similar questions have been posed before, but I have an additional caveat when I ask the following question.

How can Magento URLs be rewritten such that:

http://www.example.com/category/subcategory.html

Becomes:

http://www.example.com/subcategory.html

...**without** accessing the Admin menu or installing additional modules, and purely by editing the .htaccess file? Is there a way?

(If the .html can be stripped off the end as well, that would be terrific!)

Thank you for your time. :)

Comment: This seems a silly amount of effort.  Email the admin if you dont have access and change the single setting  designed for this.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback. Can I just double check that setting definitely affects _category_ pages and not only _product_ pages? Obviously without access at present I cannot try it to find out! :)

Comment: Maybe you are right, I'm not finding that either for categores, though answer below claims differently.  This option is available with seo extensions.

Answer (score 4):

**To remove category paths from product url** set `"Use Categories Path for Product URLs"` to `"No"` under `System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Search Engine Optimizations`.

**To remove parent category path from child category url** 
Rewrite class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Url`
override method `public function getCategoryRequestPath($category, $parentPath)` like below

```
public function getCategoryRequestPath($category, $parentPath)
    {
        $storeId = $category->getStoreId();
        $idPath  = $this->generatePath('id', null, $category);
        $suffix  = $this->getCategoryUrlSuffix($storeId);

        if (isset($this->_rewrites[$idPath])) {
            $this->_rewrite = $this->_rewrites[$idPath];
            $existingRequestPath = $this->_rewrites[$idPath]->getRequestPath();
        }

        if ($category->getUrlKey() == '') {
            $urlKey = $this->getCategoryModel()->formatUrlKey($category->getName());
        }
        else {
            $urlKey = $this->getCategoryModel()->formatUrlKey($category->getUrlKey());
        }

        $categoryUrlSuffix = $this->getCategoryUrlSuffix($category->getStoreId());
        // Code commented to remove parent category path from child category path
        //if (null === $parentPath) {
            //$parentPath = $this->getResource()->getCategoryParentPath($category);
        //}
        //elseif ($parentPath == '/') {
            $parentPath = '';
        //}
        $parentPath = Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getCategoryUrlPath($parentPath,
                                                                           true, $category->getStoreId());

        $requestPath = $parentPath . $urlKey . $categoryUrlSuffix;
        if (isset($existingRequestPath) && $existingRequestPath == $requestPath . $suffix) {
            return $existingRequestPath;
        }

        if ($this->_deleteOldTargetPath($requestPath, $idPath, $storeId)) {
            return $requestPath;
        }

        return $this->getUnusedPath($category->getStoreId(), $requestPath,
                                    $this->generatePath('id', null, $category)
        );
    }
```

Modified below code

```
if (null === $parentPath) {
            $parentPath = $this->getResource()->getCategoryParentPath($category);
        }
        elseif ($parentPath == '/') {
            $parentPath = '';
        }
```

to

```
//if (null === $parentPath) {
            //$parentPath = $this->getResource()->getCategoryParentPath($category);
        //}
        //elseif ($parentPath == '/') {
            $parentPath = '';
        //}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is hard to do it via htacces you only need to change few settings at the backend:

1. Go to the Magento Admin Panel -> System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Seo Options
2. Select yes or no from "Use Parent Category Path for Category URLs"
3. Refresh category url index

Option YES => http://www.example.com/category/subcategory.html

Option NO => http://www.example.com/subcategory.html

Comment: I am not able to see that option. `Use Parent Category Path for Category URLs`. is it for Magento2.

Comment: No M1, for M2 please see https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/126732/magento-2-how-to-remove-parent-categories-slug-from-subcategory-urls-to-make-i

Answer (score 1):

Go to `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php` and copy this file to `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php`

Edit the copied file and around line number 726, you can find below code:

```
$requestPath = $parentPath . $urlKey . $categoryUrlSuffix;
```

change it to below code:

```
$requestPath = $urlKey . $categoryUrlSuffix;
```

Then update it.

Flush Magento cache and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `.htaccess`

```
#moving to new url structure
Redirect 301 http://domain.com/parent-category/subcategory.html http://domain.com/category.html
```

But It's Not a good practice every time you create a menu and then rewrite here. 
Then to much of 301 redirection is not good for SEO Also.

If you want you can try. But before you take Backup