# Remove parent category URL for a given storeId but not all other storeId

Tags: magento-1.8, category, url, seo

On a multi-site setup, I need to remove the parent category path from the child category URLs, but to do it for only 1 of the storeIDs.

The solution by Anshu Mishra linked below works, but it removes the paths from every store. I require it to only remove the paths from 1 store.

[Remove parent categories from subcategory URLs](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/55368/remove-parent-categories-from-subcategory-urls)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

For achieve ,need  some customization at class  [`Mage_Catalog_Model_Url`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php#698) at function [`getCategoryRequestPath()`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php#717)

On this function,you can get store  id from  `$storeId = $category->getStoreId();`

**Change:**

```
   if (null === $parentPath) {
        $parentPath = $this->getResource()->getCategoryParentPath($category);
    }
    elseif ($parentPath == '/') {
        $parentPath = '';
    }
```

**to**

```
/* Store id is not match Your certain store id   then do default */
if($storeId!='YOU_Store_id' ):
if (null === $parentPath) {
        $parentPath = $this->getResource()->getCategoryParentPath($category);
    }
    elseif ($parentPath == '/') {
        $parentPath = '';
}
endif;
```

**Note: You need to rewrite class  that class as good quality code and change code at this function**