# Custom URL Rewrites - Deleting after reindex

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite

I've researched this problem but still I have got no idea on how to fix it.

So, I worked on creating a proper menu structure for my products and by doing so, I have made categories with the intention of linking them up to the url taken from my layered navigation, let me try and explain:

I created a category called: Cases & Accessories --> Computer Cases --> Full Tower ('Full tower' being the type of products, filtered out)

I get the required URL by using my layered navigation, filtering the type of computer case which leaves me a URL of:  **XXX/cases-accessories/computer-cases.html?i_form_factor_771_1=6967** where i realised i cannot use special characters in the URL key inside catalog --> manage categories,  then I start to create a custom url rewrite

The setup of the custom URL rewrite works perfectly, so I delete the system generated rewrite but when i reindex the catalog url writes, it generates a new system rewrite with a higher ID so uses that over the custom one with now a lower ID.

I tried another option which was to edit the system generated one, which only allows me to change the request path, I do this then reindex but again, the default request path is back on.

Here is a screenshot:
[image: Custom URL Rewrite]

You see, the ID for the custom is currently higher but the front end is still showing the system url rewrite. For me to reflect the custom rewrite, i would have to delete the system one.

**Futher screenshot reflecting the comments**:
[image]

This seemed to work, so i now need to change the 1st system rewrite from cases-accessories/computer-cases/full-tower-cases.html to fulltower.html, i try doing this inside the system rewrite, but after a reindex it changes back to cases-accessories/computer-cases/full-tower-cases.html. Any ideas? I created a 3rd url write with the target path of "catalog/category/view/id/1234" but it didnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this helps or not but I think i had a similar problem...

find the system created URL rewrite for the category tree you have created

change the redirect to Permanent 301

[image]

before you save copy the target path...

Then create a custom URL rewrite placing the copied target path into the custom url rewrite request path.

[image]

Update your new target path to where you want the category link to go. (My example goes to a CMS page with a URL key of "dry-eye") I believe this should stop the indexing affecting the link as you technically don't change any of the system rewrite info, instead you add a new rewrite that will apply after the system one.

I could be completely misunderstanding your question though :/

Comment: ok, now im really confused, are you saying you cant put "/cases-accessories/computer-cases?i_form_factor_771_1=6967" in the new target path as the GET data will change?

Comment: re-indexing the urls should retain the order of which the rewrites were added, if it doesn't I believe there is something fundamentally wrong with your magento install

Comment: try changing your custom rewrite request path from "full-tower-cases.html" to "catalog/category/view/id/1234" this should mean the system rewrite will run, then your custom one will pick up the request / target from the system rewrite and send to the custom target path

Comment: you might need to change your system rewrite to "redirect permanent" for it to work (im not 100% though) worth a ttry

Comment: I've added another screenshot, your suggestion seemed to work! Thanks. I now need to find a way to get the target path to show full-tower-cases.html instead of cases-accessories/computer-cases/full-tower-cases.html, i try changing this within the system rewrite, but after reindex it changes straight back. (i have deleted my unneccessary comments before your solution)

Comment: Thats great! if you could accept this answer it would be appreciated! I think your next problem should be an easy one!

goto: System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Search Engine Optimizations

then change "Use Categories Path for Product URLs" to No

Comment: I've already had that option to no before having this problem, any other suggestion?

Comment: if that change didnt work Im guessing its due to the custom rewrite, have a look at this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/55368/remove-parent-categories-from-subcategory-urls. I dont think you will be able to achieve your desired outcome without writing a custom module, or manually editing .htaccess

Comment: the above it outside my knowledge bracket :(

Comment: To my last question to you, i fixed it by simply using a different ID Path, i was using the same ID path as the system which resulted in the reindex to clear the given options. Now i can have the request path to anything i want and with RP staying. Your answer got me here, so thanks again.

Comment: Thats great! glad I could help!

Comment: @AndrewBramwell URL Rewrite Management not working after Re-indexed For Category Redirect https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/210130/57334

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this same problem.
Magento does not support "custom url rewrites" in admin panel for many reasons.

**You have 3 options:** *Easiest to Hardest*

1. Utilize a Static block
2. RewriteEngine On. Add your exception (`.htaccess`)
3. Interpret & Modify (`index.php`)

Any other method will revert on **Reindex**