# Magento 2 - How to remove parent categories slug from subcategory URLs to make it shorter?

Tags: magento2, category, magento-2.1

I want to remove the trailing category in magento 2

```
http://magento2.dev/accessories/tops-women.html
http://magento2.dev/accessories/tops-women/jackets-women.html
```

instead I want

```
http://magento2.dev/tops-women.html
http://magento2.dev/jackets-women.html
```

Comment: Problem with mit index.html now
to many redirects https://shop.domain.de routes to
https://shop.domain.de// Any idea how to fix?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/136909)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We can configure it by **URL Rewrites**

1. Go to Magento 2 Admin -> Marketing -> SEO & Search -> URL Rewrites
2. Find the path by searching `Request path` column.
3. Remove the cache `php bin/magento cache:clean`.
4. Refresh the front-end, click the main menu category then you can see the configured path.

Example i have modified.

Request path `men/tops-men/tees-men.htm`

Modified path `tees-men.htm`

**Or**

You Can Build category URL path by

```
\vendor\magento\module-catalog-url-rewrite\Model\CategoryUrlPathGenerator.php
```

Modify `getUrlPath($category)` by Magento Plug-in feature.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Using this I have to do it one by one. and when creating new category it again create nested url. 
any solution that do it directly when create new category or update category

Comment: Have a look at the modified answer.

Comment: thank that was helpful

Answer (score 11):

As pointed out by @Rajan Soni, you need to override the native Magento class :

> - vendor\magento\module-catalog-url-rewrite\Model\CategoryUrlPathGenerator.php

To do so, you need to use an existing module, or to create to a new dedicated one.
You will need 4 files, located in your new module Vendor_Module directory :

> - app/code/Vendor/Module/
> - app/code/Vendor/Module/registration.php
> - app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml
> - app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml
> - app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/CategoryUrlPathGenerator.php

**app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence></sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**app/code/Vendor/Module/registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

**app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\CategoryUrlPathGenerator" type="Vendor\Module\Model\CategoryUrlPathGenerator" />
</config>
```

**app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/CategoryUrlPathGenerator.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Category;
use Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\CategoryUrlPathGenerator as Magento_CategoryUrlPathGenerator;

class CategoryUrlPathGenerator extends Magento_CategoryUrlPathGenerator {

    public function getUrlPath($category, $parentCategory = null)
    {
        if (in_array($category->getParentId(), [Category::ROOT_CATEGORY_ID, Category::TREE_ROOT_ID])) {
            return '';
        }
        $path = $category->getUrlPath();
        if ($path !== null && !$category->dataHasChangedFor('url_key') && !$category->dataHasChangedFor('parent_id')) {
            return $path;
        }
        $path = $category->getUrlKey();
        if ($path === false) {
            return $category->getUrlPath();
        }

        return $path;
    }    
}
```

Then as usual, you will probably need to refresh some stuff :

> - bin/magento module:enable Vendor_Module;
> - bin/magento cache:clean;
> - bin/magento setup:di:compile;
> - bin/magento setup:upgrade;
> - bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f;

As noticed above, you could also need to refresh "url_rewrite" table, and save / reindex categories.

PS : @Siarhey Uchukhlebau suggested to implement a fix with the plugin way, which I agree would be probably better than the "preference" solution provided, especially if you already had an extension which override this same class.

*// I am pretty new to M2, so any suggestion about my post would be appreciated !*

See ya

Comment: Thanks, added as module https://github.com/magefast/CategoryNoParentPath

Comment: This extension is useful when creating new sub categories but is doesn't change URLs of already created sub categories. Any idea how to remove parent path from already created categories?

Answer (score 2):

Sort and sweet solution for this is:

Just go to the file: 
\vendor\magento\module-catalog-url-rewrite\Model\CategoryUrlPathGenerator.php 
or
**Just override that file**

In the getUrlPath() function just comment this code

```
/*if ($this->isNeedToGenerateUrlPathForParent($category)) {
        $parentPath = $this->getUrlPath(
            $this->categoryRepository->get($category->getParentId(), $category->getStoreId())
        );
        $parentPath ="";
        //$path = $parentPath === '' ? $path : $parentPath . '/' . $path;
        $path = $parentPath === '' ? $path : $path;
    }*/
```

And open the database find the table ***url_rewrite*** just backup it and truncate that table.

then, go to your admin > products > categories
choose any one category and save that.

then check your frontend.

Your problem will be solve.

Comment: It is not a good idea to make changes right in the core code. I recommend you to use a plugins instead.

Comment: Brother, you can override that file.

Comment: Sure, but you should edit your answer and add necessary info about that: how to overwrite whole class or how to create the around-plugin.

Comment: Ya, I edit my answer and I mention in bold to override that file bro.

Comment: You can down-vote many times, but it won't add mind for you

Comment: @RajanSoni If I override this function getUrlPath($category) then I am getting error that $category not found. Any idea?