# Why "Use Parent Category Path for Category URLs" option is not available in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, admin, magento-2.0, url-rewrite

We have a Seo Options to modify the URL visibility in **Magento 1.x**

Reference :

1. Go to the Magento Admin Panel -> System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Seo Options.
2. Select yes or no from "Use Parent Category Path for Category URLs".
3. Refresh category url index.

Option YES => http://www.example.com/category/subcategory.html

Option NO => http://www.example.com/subcategory.html

But I unable to find the option or equivalent settings in **Magento 2.x.**

Still we have a [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/126732/magento-2-how-to-remove-parent-categories-slug-from-subcategory-urls-to-make-i) to change URL visibility.

**But my question is, is there any specific reason for not providing this option in Magento 2.x or else i missed something?**

Comment: I flagged the question as **cannot be reproduced**, as this option never existed in core Magento which renders the question "why it has been removed" moot. In other words: yes, you missed something, namely that you have installed an extension in Magento 1 that added this option.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is such an option in Magento 1.9.4 - just checked now.

Comment: True. There is only "Use Categories Path for Product URLs", additional configurations must have been added with an extension.