# Magento2 category url

Tags: magento-2.1, category, url, url-rewrite

I want to change my url to the endpoint of slug on categories.
Ex:

> www.example.com/level1/level2/level3.html

should be like this:

> www.example.com/level3.html

Answer (score 1):

We can configure it by URL Rewrites

1. Go to Magento 2 **Admin -> Marketing -> SEO & Search -> URL Rewrites**
2. Find the path by searching Request path column.
3. Remove the cache `php bin/magento cache:clean`.
4. Refresh the front-end, click the main menu category then you can see the configured path.

Example I have modified.

Request path `men/tops-men/tees-men.htm`

Modified path `tees-men.htm`

Or

You Can Build category URL path by

```
\vendor\magento\module-catalog-url-rewrite\Model\CategoryUrlPathGenerator.php
```

Modify `getUrlPath($category`) by Magento Plug-in feature.

[Magento 2 - How to remove parent categories slug from subcategory URLs to make it shorter?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/126732/magento-2-how-to-remove-parent-categories-slug-from-subcategory-urls-to-make-i)

Comment: Thanks for your response, could you please give me the code for getUrlPath($category)? what should i paste?

Comment: if In feature if you are using plug-in than u need to modified.

Comment: No i have not any plugin, just need to override Magento

Comment: please click above url, there have some one is created module.