# Only show current category in category path?

Tags: magento2, category, url

**Magento 2.4**

A category looks like this: https://www.example.com/cat1/cat/cat3.html
I want it to look like this: https://www.example.com/cat3.html

So what I want is only the current category, not the full path on the category page.

I did not find a setting for that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, Magento 2 does not offer an option to "shorten" category URLs.

However, [this solution](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/126732/magento-2-how-to-remove-parent-categories-slug-from-subcategory-urls-to-make-i) might help you achieve your goal.

Otherwise, in case you don't like working manually using the above solution, there are plenty of third-party extensions out there that does this job. Simply google "Magento 2 short (or unique) category URL", you'll find a bunch of them.

Happy coding!

Comment: Great, thanks, at least I can stop looking and try an extension...no way for me to do it manually, too many URLs :-).